# Control wordpad through excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, wordpad

I have an Column with excel cells with multiple values separated by " ," or " & " (coming from a DB). How do I control wordpad through excel VBA?

Sample data -

```
1111


1112,12311,2321,12312 & 23123

12321


1111

1115

1123, 12312

1211

1111,2321 & 2321

2321 & 1211
```

O/P required is without duplicates in 1 column unique values.

Till now I have been copying the data in a sheet ---> Remove dup. values ---> Text To Columns ---> 1.seperate by '&' 2. copy the values in the 2nd column , remove dup. and blanks ---> paste it below the original data --- > Text to Columns ---> separate by ',' ---> copy the data by each if greater than 1 --> transpose and pste below the original data.

I am currently trying to achieve here - > copy all original data --> remove dup -> paste in wordpad - > replace ',' and '&' by '^p' (this was suggested by my good friend and saves me a lot of time) and replace with original data.

I have reached till pasting the data in the Wordpad and do not know how to replace the data in the wordpad through excel VBA. Can anyone help me please ?

```
            'Create and copying the required range to word
               
                Dim iTotalRows As Integer   ' GET TOTAL USED RANGE ROWS.
                iTotalRows = Worksheets("Quote #").UsedRange.Rows.Count
            
                Dim iTotalCols As Integer   ' GET TOTAL COLUMNS.
                iTotalCols = 2
                
                
                ' WORD OBJECT.
                Dim oWord As Object
                Set oWord = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
                oWord.Visible = True
                oWord.Activate
                
                ' ADD A DOCUMENT TO THE WORD OBJECT.
                Dim oDoc
                Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
                
                ' CREATE A RANGE FOR THE TABLE INSIDE WORD DOCUMENT.
                Dim oRange
                Set oRange = oDoc.Range
            
                ' CREATE AND  DEFINE TABLE STRUCTURE USING
                    ' THE ROWS AND COLUMNS EXTRACTED FROM EXCEL USED RANGE.
                oDoc.Tables.Add oRange, iTotalRows, iTotalCols
            
                ' CREATE A TABLE OBJECT.
                Dim oTable
                Set oTable = oDoc.Tables(1)
                'oTable.Borders.Enable = True
            
                Dim iRows, iCols As Integer
            
                ' LOOP THROUGH EACH ROW AND COLUMN TO EXTRACT DATA IN EXCEL.
                For iRows = 1 To iTotalRows
                    For iCols = 1 To iTotalCols
                        Dim txt As Variant
                        txt = Worksheets("Quote #").Cells(iRows, iCols)
                        oTable.cell(iRows, iCols).Range.Text = txt        ' COPY (OR WRITE) DATA TO THE TABLE.
            
                        ' BOLD HEADERS.
                        'If Val(iRows) = 1 Then
                         '   objTable.cell(iRows, iCols).Range.Font.Bold = True
                        'End If
                    Next iCols
                Next iRows
                
                'to replace text code reference source pasted below
                
                With oWord.ActiveDocument.Content.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                
                .Text = ","
                .Replacement.Text = "^p"
                .wrap = 1 '.Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                .Execute Replace:=2 'reference : - 
                End With
                
                Set oWord = Nothing
```

I am trying to replace "," or "&" with "^p" which word will consider as a new line. Hope this helps.

O/P required : -

1112

12311

2321

12312

23123

12321

1111

1115

1123

1211

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code, you can post? [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I have found a solution but it is not correct.

Comment: So how do I make the character delete and make the numbers go to the next line ?

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly. By the code this seems to be on Word and not Excel.

Comment: @Storax I have edited the code. Let me know please.

Comment: Could you also add the expected result?

Comment: I have edited the same with O/P required. It is with no duplicates, no commas, no special chars. in one column. @Storax

Comment: You have duplicates in the desired result, e.g. 1111. Is that wanted?

Comment: removed that duplicate. @storax. my bad.

Comment: Just to be sure, you still have one duplicate in the list ;-)

Comment: tell me the number. @Storax . To make it easy.

Comment: 2321 :-) is the number

Comment: Thanks. That was quick. Done, removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on the comments and the post Word is not needed to remove the duplicates. I suggest to use a [dictionary](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) here. Sample code for the following situtation. The desired output to my understanding should be like in column C

[image]

The following code will do this

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveDuplicatesFromDBExtract()

Const COMMA = ","
Const AMPERSAND = "&"

Dim i As Long
Dim rg As Range
Dim sngCell As Range
Dim vDat As Variant
Dim vContent As Variant

' Add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime
' Select Tools->References from the Visual Basic menu.
' Check box beside "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" in the list.
Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    ' Adjust for your need
    Set rg = Range("A1:A9")

    For Each sngCell In rg
        vContent = Replace(sngCell.Value, COMMA, vbCrLf)
        vContent = Replace(vContent, AMPERSAND, vbCrLf)
        vDat = Split(vContent, vbCrLf)

        For i = LBound(vDat) To UBound(vDat)
            On Error Resume Next
            ' If vdat(i) is already in the dictionary it will not be added twice
            dict.Add Trim(vDat(i)), Trim(vDat(i))
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i

    Next sngCell

    ' Write output, adjust for your needs
    Range("C1").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Items)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I have never heard of scripting dictionary. Will definitely try to implement it, this will save us a lot of time. @Storax.

Comment: Then let's hope you do not work with a Mac as it is not availabe on that [platform](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58473fb2-8846-4e44-a05a-a97eb963c41d/scripting-dictionary-on-a-mac?forum=Office2016forMac).

Comment: Woah, just 1 try and it worked :) you're awesome @Storax

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks!